# Selenium webdriver blocked Cloudflare. Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am using selenium to analyze other sites, and on those sites cloudflare blocks it. How to make Cloudflare not block webdriver?

`Versions used:: 93, 65, 70, 86`. Everybody doesn't work

Not working сhromedriver arguments:

```
--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled

--disable-setuid-sandbox

--no-zygote
```

and many others

**ProtonVPN, windscribe VPN:**

I used `3-4 different IPs` on each VPN. Blocks every.

In Winscribe I used paid account - blocks anyway

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yi2FV.png)

Comment: Cloudflare offers a bot detection service.  Turn that off when running automated tests.

Comment: I am using selenium to parse other sites and these sites have blocked selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch to Playwright and use Firefox or WebKit in headless mode(Chromium somehow can still be detected).

Comment: Our project is using Python 3.6, and we need to find a solution for selenium with chrome because the core of our project write for chrome

Comment: Decided to use it, since they did not find any other options. thanks

Comment: Also, you can change user agent maybe it will work.